Type '{ public_id: string; url: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentArray<{ public_id: string; url: string; }>':
Error: Type '{ public_id: string; url: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentArray<{ public_id: string; url: string; }>': isMongooseDocumentArray, create, id, $pop, and 8 more.
I am getting error at product.photos = photosURL;
It is working fine when assigning value using await Product.create({photos: photosURL});
export const updateProduct = TryCatch(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { name, price, stock, category, description } = req.body;
    const photos = req.files as Express.Multer.File[] | undefined;
  
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
  
    if (!product) return next(new ErrorHandler("Product Not Found", 404));
  
    if (photos && photos.length > 0) {
      const photosURL = await uploadToCloudinary(photos);
  
      const ids = product.photos.map((photo) => photo.public_id);
  
      await deleteFromCloudinary(ids);
  
      product.photos = photosURL;
    }

I having following in Product schema:
photos: [
            {
              public_id: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Please enter Public ID"],
              },
              url: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Please enter URL"],
              },
            },
          ],

const getBase64 = (file: Express.Multer.File) =>
  `data:${file.mimetype};base64,${file.buffer.toString("base64")}`;

export const uploadToCloudinary = async (files: Express.Multer.File[]) => {
  const promises = files.map(async (file) => {
    return new Promise<UploadApiResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
      cloudinary.uploader.upload(getBase64(file), (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result!);
      });
    });
  });

  const result = await Promise.all(promises);

  return result.map((i) => ({
    public_id: i.public_id,
    url: i.secure_url,
  }));
};


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please consider [edit]ing this code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now this seems to  depend on types or values that are undeclared, unimported, third-party, or private. So others will mostly see errors unrelated to your question.

The error occurs because you're assigning an array of plain objects ({ public_id: string; url: string; }[]) to a Mongoose DocumentArray (product.photos). This mismatch leads to the error since Mongoose expects a DocumentArray with specific methods, but you're passing a regular array.
You need to map the array of objects (photosURL) into Mongoose subdocuments before assigning them. Here's the updated code:
product.photos = photosURL.map(photo => ({
  public_id: photo.public_id,
  url: photo.url,
}));

Full Code:
export const updateProduct = TryCatch(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { name, price, stock, category, description } = req.body;
    const photos = req.files as Express.Multer.File[] | undefined;
  
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
  
    if (!product) return next(new ErrorHandler("Product Not Found", 404));
  
    if (photos && photos.length > 0) {
      const photosURL = await uploadToCloudinary(photos);
  
      const ids = product.photos.map((photo) => photo.public_id);
      await deleteFromCloudinary(ids);
  
      product.photos = photosURL.map((photo) => ({
        public_id: photo.public_id,
        url: photo.url,
      }));
    }

    product.name = name;
    product.price = price;
    product.stock = stock;
    product.category = category;
    product.description = description;
  
    await product.save();
  
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      product,
    });
});

// Product Schema:
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  stock: Number,
  category: String,
  description: String,
  photos: [
    {
      public_id: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter Public ID"],
      },
      url: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter URL"],
      },
    },
  ],
});


Thank you for looking into it.
I am still getting same error even after using map to assign values.
Error: Type '{ public_id: string; url: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentArray<{ public_id: string; url: string; }>': isMongooseDocumentArray, create, id, $pop, and 8 more.ts(2740)

Instead of overwriting the array, you can add new items individually using push. This ensures that Mongoose handles each element as a subdocument properly: product.photos = []; // Clear the old photos first.
photosURL.forEach((photo) => {
product.photos.push({
public_id: photo.public_id,
url: photo.url,
});
});
